# Is there anyway to find if a particular answer has been posted for a question with many answers?

Tags: support, search, answers

Sometimes questions can have answers leading to pages. Reading them all to judge if a particular answer I've in my mind has been already posted is a bit tedious. For eg, in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) (for example sake), there's a good chance that I would be posting a duplicate answer.

Which would only lead to down votes. So some solution? An added feature like searching within a question would help really.

Comment: Well... I wouldn't be *too* worried about posting a duplicate answer on that question in particular.

Comment: Yes but that's just an example.

Comment: *"Reading them all ... is a bit tedious."* Yeah, this is a problem I have a lot. Hope we can figure out some way of solving it.

Comment: @Cody Gray See the link I posted and decide how do you feel. Moreover a neat workaround is posted below for us to feel happy :)

Comment: Yes. I saw the link you posted. That's about the *only* question that this even makes sense for. Since those kinds of questions are no longer allowed around here, there's not much point in such a feature.

Comment: @Cody Gray  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java  see this question which was asked last month I suppose. I would say the answer given by Tim is always handy here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`inquestion:<id>` search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/search). For example, you can search for [posts containing "lambda"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A9033+lambda) in your example question.

Note that if you're viewing the question you want to search in, using `inquestion:this` in the search box will save you the trouble of typing the question ID manually.

Comment: I cant even upvote, wth! :)

Comment: @nawful - I up-voted this for you. This is a +1 from me, and a +1 from nawful (in spirit). That's right folks, new feature - virtual votes.

Comment: @Tim Post Virtual votes? What on earth is that? :-o

Comment: @nawful an obviously failed attempt at humor.

Comment: @Tim Post haha. No, I thought mods can vote more than once, since I got two votes at that time. :)

Answer (score 4):

Something to consider: If a question really has *so many answers* that it's too tedious to read through them all to be sure you're posting something new, is anyone really going to read through the answers anyway? Seems to me like a good sign that there's probably not much point to adding another answer at all.

Of course, I'd also wager that any question attracting that many answers should probably be *closed with extreme prejudice*. There's not many legitimate questions that would get that kind of response, I think.

Comment: I understand that. But my question wasnt for such questions. Sometimes nature of questions can vary. See the example link I gave you. It can always have answers anytime. But I need to confirm if it has been posted or not. Anyways thanks for chiming in :)

Comment: + 1  The platonic ideal of an SO thread is a question with one (accepted) answer.  There are some questions, dating back to the early days, which gave lots of answers worth readings.  These are the poll type questions - favourite programming cartoon, worst UI design - which would be closed immediately these days.